# Number Pyramids on Java with decreasing numbers

Tags: java, numbers

I'm trying to do make a number pyramid on java like this with an input;
Assume that n is 7;

```
7654321
 654321
  54321
   4321
    321
     21
      1
```

This is my code;

```
for(int column = 1; n >= column; column++){
    for(int row = 1; n >=row; row++) {
        if(column <= row) { // Observe what will happen if we use == or <= or > or <>
            System.out.print(row);
        } else {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println(' ');
}
```

And it gives me numbers like this;

```
1234567
 234567
  34567
   4567
    567
     67
      7
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the code that controls the value of `row`, and observe that `row` is *increasing*. If you want to print a decreasing sequence, you could either

- Change the loop to iterate from `n` down to `1`, using `row--`, or
- Print `n-row+1` in the `System.out.print(...)` call.

Comment: Thanks i will give reputation when i be able to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Below code works. You just need to print the value of n-row+1 or else Make your loop to start with the value of n and decrement the row and print the row.

```
 for(int column = 1; n >= column; column++){
        for(int row = 1; n >=row; row++) {
            if(column < row) { // Observe what will happen if we use == or <= or > or <>
                System.out.print(n-row+1);
            } else {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println(' ');
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works too good. I'll give reputation when i able to do that.